# disable automatic tag insertion in specific page template

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

puting this code in `function.php`

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );
```

It disable automatic `<p>` and `<br />` tag insertion in page `template`.

for example I have 3 `page template` which is `index.php`, `single.php` and `taxonomy.php` and all of that `page template` remove the automatic `<p>` and `<br />` insertion, in my case, I want `<p>` and `<br />` tag `automatic` in `taxonomy.php`. is tha posible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one....

It disable automatic `<p>` and `<br />` in specific `post` and `costume post type`.

```
function wpc_remove_autop_for_posttype( $content )  
      {  
    // edit the post type here  
    'costume_post_type' === get_post_type() && remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
    return $content;  
   }  
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpc_remove_autop_for_posttype', 0 );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`is_tax()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_tax) to check if you are displaying the taxonomy archive page and only remove the filters if it does not return `true`.

```
if ( ! is_tax() ){
    remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
    remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );
}
```

Comment: I guess its better way!

Comment: thank your for taking time to answer my question... but unfortunately it's not working when I copy paste it to my `function.php`

Comment: This will **not** process on the taxonomy page but will remove the filter everywhere else. Are you looking for it to only remove the filter on the taxonomy page?

Comment: Also from the docs: Note that `is_tax()` returns false on category archives and tag archives. You should use `is_category()` and `is_tag()` respectively when checking for category and tag archives

Comment: yes... if that possible, if I am in `taxonomy page template` I want `<p>` and `<br />` are automatic.

Comment: That is what the code above does, it will remove the `wpautop` filter from all templates except `taxonomy`.

Comment: Try testing it by writing to the error log `error_log('is_tax() is '.(is_tax()? 'true' : 'false'));`